# path : Django 2.2 path converter

Tags: django, url, django-views

I must miss something on how to work with path (not the function, the path converter). I don't understand why the None value in the following :

I have an url :

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'(<path:current_path>)?', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
]
```

A view :

```
def index(request, current_path):
    logger.error(f'current_path : {current_path}')
    path = request.path
    ...
```

Everything functions except that current_path value remains None, whatever is the given path, while request.path holds the correct value.

Why ?

**Edit :** I expected current_path = 'home/user' when I pass the following url : http://127.0.0.1:8080/file_system//home/user/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `re_path` in your pattern. That uses regexes rather than path converters. You should use `path` instead, and remove the regex parts.

```
path('<path:current_path>', views.index, name='index'),
```

Comment: My search in the docs let the subject unclear if we can or not use regex with path converters. Now I know this is the right course of actions : no we can't. Thanks !